# facebook page plugin not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need a embedded facebook page plugin. 
But the code generator of facebook doesn't work. When i give the url of the facebook page, the generator doens't give the code for this page.

Also doesn't appear the page in the preview modus.

The facebook page is: https://www.facebook.com/Tapas.Enschede/

The code generator is on this page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

For other facebookpages the code generator works perfect. I have no idea what the problem is.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: what kind of restrictions are on the page? I couldn't view it myself and if you're also restricted you can't view it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue today.

Check to see if:

1. Your page is unpublished.
2. You have Age Restriction (which was my issue) activated. Any age restriction above 13+ will cause the page plugin to not work.
3. You have Country Restrictions activated.

Any of the above will cause the page plugin not to display.

You can find these settings in the General tab in your page settings.

Comment: Today (2021), there's an additional condition : you must be connected to facebook.

Comment: To find the Country and Age restrictions in 2023, look under Settings > Privacy > [Public Posts](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=followers)

Answer (score 6):

use data-show-posts="true" instead of data-tabs="timeline"

Comment: This indeed works.

Answer (score 2):

```
 In my case,I remove the heading (h4) from the class="fb-page".Working now.
```

**Old Code**

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/"
                         data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false"
                         data-adapt-container-width="true"
                         data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">

                        <h4 class="center">Follow Us On Facebook</h4>


                        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a
                                href="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/">Testing.</a></blockquote>


                    </div>
```

**New Code**

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/"
                             data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false"
                             data-adapt-container-width="true"
                             data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">



                            <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a
                                    href="https://www.facebook.com/PageTest/">Testing.</a></blockquote>


                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it was due to some stale Facebook Cookies on my browser. Deleted the Facebook Cookies, refreshed and all worked great then

Comment: Until you log back into Facebook on Chrome browser, which puts the cookies back and the problem comes back.

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same issue - got it to work by changing the code from **data-tabs="timeline"** to **data-show-posts="true"**

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v16.0" nonce="FxrxkDNL"></script>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXXX" data-show-posts="true" data-width="800px" data-height="1000px" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXXX" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXXX">FB page</a></blockquote></div>
```